# Show picture of choice as folder thumbnail

Tags: windows, windows-vista, thumbnails

I have lots of folders full of images from family events and it seems vista picks the worst one to show me whats in there. I usually cant tell from the image what the set is and some folders have multiple subsets. Is there a tool or method i can use to swap the image for my folders?

Answer (score 7):

- Right click the folder and select Properties
- In the "Customize" tab under "Folder Pictures" select "Choose File"
- Select which image you'd like displayed for that folder and hit OK.

[image]